# Using (perminder klair dropzone wedgit) in yii2 for drpzone, file save in folder but do not save in database

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I am using `perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone` wedgit in Yii2 to upload multiple file in folder and in database. But I am getting problem, the file does not save in database, but saved in folder. How can I save file in database?

In view:-

```
echo \kato\DropZone::widget([
   'options' => [
    'url' => 'index.php?r=employee-tab/upload',
       'maxFilesize' => '2',
   ],
   'clientEvents' => [
       'complete' => "function(file){console.log(file)}",
       'removedfile' => "function(file){alert(file.name + ' is removed')}"
   ],
]);
```

in controller:-

```
public function actionCreate()
{
  $model = new EmployeeTab();

  $fileName = 'file';
  $uploadPath = 'uploads';

  if (isset($_FILES[$fileName])) {
    $file = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstanceByName($fileName);

    //Print file data
    //print_r($file);

    if ($file->saveAs($uploadPath . '/' . $file->name)) {
      //Now save file data to database

      echo \yii\helpers\Json::encode($file);
    }
  }
  else{
    return $this->render('create', [
      'model' => $model, ]);
  }

  return false;
}
```